# Canvas draw rectangle android

Tags: android, android-canvas, autolayout

> ```
>      public static Bitmap getCircularBitmapWithWhiteBorder(Bitmap bitmap,
>         int borderWidth) {
>     if (bitmap == null || bitmap.isRecycled()) {
>         return null;
>     }
>     final int width = bitmap.getWidth() + borderWidth;
>     final int height = bitmap.getHeight() + borderWidth;
>     Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width*2, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
>     BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
>     Paint paint = new Paint();
>     paint.setAntiAlias(true);
>     paint.setShader(shader);
>     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
>     float radius = width > height ? ((float) height) / 2f : ((float) width) / 2f;
>     canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, paint);
>     paint.setShader(null);
>     paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
>     paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
>     paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
>     canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius - borderWidth / 2, paint);      
>     return canvasBitmap;
> }
> ```

I have circular image, i want to attach next to circular image sort of a rectangle..similar to his
[image]
this is a circle, next to it there is a rectangle attached. how can I do this?

Comment: the rectabgle is 3 sides, only one missing is the one attached to rounded circular image

Comment: click on image link to see the image better cause background somewhat transparent http://i.stack.imgur.com/1UGEb.png

Answer (score 0):

You could draw your Rectangle more or less like this:

```
  canvas.drawRect(width/2 + radius, height/2 - radius, width , height, paint);
```

just adjust the parameters for positioning it correctly if needed